# CSS Sprites - How to align and make responsive?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

How to align icons where i want them to be?
Example code:

```
    <div id="details_info">
    <div class="pirmais">
        <img src="img/gtavice.png" width="100%" height="200">
    </div>

<div class="otrais">
    <h2>Grand Theft Auto: Vice City</h2>
        <p>Rockstar games <div class="popular"></div></p>
        <p><div class="s-18"></div>PEGI 18</p>
</div>
```

I want popular icon be next to Rockstar games but it's shown under the text.

I got s-18 icon to show on the left of PEGI with float:left but i can't use it everywhere. For example using float:right for Rockstar games will put icon to the bottom right.

```
.s-18, .cilveks, .gljuk, .icon_earth, .icon_flag, .icon_mail, .icon_shield, .like, .plus, .popular, .profile_pic, .stars{
    background: url(../img/sprites.png) no-repeat;
}

.popular{
    background-position: -368px -19px ;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
}

.s-18{
    background-position: -11px -10px ;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    float:left;
}
#details_info {
    max-width:100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
#details_info .pirmais {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#details_info .otrais{
    width: 60%; 
    float: left;
}

#details_info .otrais img{
    width: 5%; 
}
```

Aswell how to make make theese sprites responsive? I'm first time creating something responsive and don't know much about media queries so i'm using some kind of % to scale website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.popular` is shown under the text because it's still a block. Give it `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`.

Same for other icons such as `.s-18` which would also be better off as inline-blocks than as floats.

To make sprites responsive, what you need to do is create a higher resolution version of the sprite image.

So if your sprite image normally looks like this

[image: two small circles]

<sup>(I don't have your sprites here, so I had to roll my own, sorry)</sup>

you do something like

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgVDK.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: -14px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```

So for a higher resolution picture, you simply make a larger version of the graphic, and tell the browser that you want to display it at the same size, in this case 28px × 14px, so it will get scaled down.
The rest of the code can stay the same.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN6uj.png') no-repeat; /* changed */
  background-position: -14px 0;
  background-size: 28px 14px; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```

If you don't see the difference between the two results, try zooming in!

Comment: Worked like a charm, sir :) Any clues on how to make these sprites responsive? :)

Comment: Responsive in what way? Do you want the image sizes to depend on the resolution of the device?

Comment: Yes, i want image sizes to depend on the resolution :)

Comment: I tried to use this one: http://responsive-css.spritegen.com/ , it does work, but i want to create icons from <div class> and not from <img> so i have less http requests.

Comment: OK, I edited the answer with, hopefully, enough information to get you going.